# Unpack a list outside of a function for pandas DataFrame multi-index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I want to add a multi-index column to an existing pandas dataframe `df`. An example:

```
d = {('a','b'):[1,2,3], ('c', 'd'): [4,5,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

The resulting dataframe is:

```
   a  c 
   b  d 
0  1  4 
1  2  5 
2  3  6
```

Now I want to add a new column to the dataframe. The correct way to do that would be to use `df['e', 'f'] = [7,8,9]`. However, I would like to use the list `new_key` as the key. Normally I could use the asterisk `*`, but apparently it cannot be used outside of functions. So I get the following errors.

```
new_key = ['e','f']

df[new_key] = [7,8,9]
> KeyError: "['e' 'f'] not in index"

df[*new_key] = [7,8,9]
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast to a **`tuple`** first:

```
df[tuple(new_key)] = [7,8,9]

   a  c  e
   b  d  f
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
```

Comment: Doh! Thank you very much! Works!

Comment: It's counterintuitive you need to do this, especially since `df['e', 'f']`, works, which would seem to imply unpacking should too.  Happy to help!